# OCaml: Type mismatch error between modules

Tags: ocaml

### ast.ml

```ml
type fundef = FunDef of string * string list * expr
```

### interpreter.ml

```ml
let interp_fundef (d: Ast.fundef) (g: FStore.t) : FStore.t = 
  match d with
  | Ast.FunDef (x, pl, e) -> (FStore.add x (pl * e) g)
```

### fStore.ml

```ml
module M = Map.Make(String)

type t = (string list * Ast.expr) M.t

let add = M.add

let mem = M.mem

let find = M.find

let empty = M.empty
```

I am making a f1vae AST interpreter with OCaml and above is my current code.
When compilng, I am getting this error on `pl` in interpreter.ml:

```
Error: This expression has type string list
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `g` is of type `FStore.t` then the map holds a tuple of type `string list * Ast.expr`. However, you have tried to add into that map `(pl * e)`. Here the operator `*` dictates that `pl` and `e` must be values of type `int`.

You likely meant to write the following, which creates a tuple of `pl` and `e` using a comma.

```
let interp_fundef (d: Ast.fundef) (g: FStore.t) : FStore.t = 
  match d with
  | Ast.FunDef (x, pl, e) -> (FStore.add x (pl, e) g)
```

This mistake based on the disparity between tuple *type* and tuple *value* syntax is easy to make, but fundamental, so important to understand.

```
# (4, 5);;
- : int * int = (4, 5)
```

I might suggest writing this as follows, avoiding binding the unneeded `d` name.

```
let interp_fundef (Ast.Fundef (x, pl, e)) (g : FStore.t) : FStore.t =
  FStore.add x (pl, e) g
```